# Reset ISODate with time stamp to midnight in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I have a use case to query as below.

The time stamp passed would like `2018-09-01T12:23:32`  like **ISODate**. Mongo version **3.5**. How to query in such cases?

```
    mongo_client.find(
  "date":{
      '$gte': {<midnight on the date of date key},
      '$lt': {<searchkey with time stamp>}
  })
```

Comment: You need to calculate both dates on application layer. As a side note, 3.5 is a very rare version which is not even listed in https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy. Out of curiosity, what are the reasons to stick to to it?  It  has no updates since September.

Answer (score 0):

you can create start and end dates, use it for querying

```
> var end = new Date("2018-01-30T04:05:23.974Z")
ISODate("2018-01-30T04:05:23.974Z")

> var start = new Date("2018-01-30")
ISODate("2018-01-30T00:00:00Z")

> db.col.find({date : {$gte : start}, date : {$lt : end}})
```